# $6000 of employment income or employment income of $6000

Tags: word-order

(1) If you have earned **$6000 of employment income** maximum this year, you will not need to declare income tax next year.

(2) If you have earned **an employment income of $6000** maximum this year, you will not need to declare income tax next year.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Americans tend to talk in terms of "deductions"  and the standard deduction is a lot more than $6000.  British tend to talk in terms of "allowance".

Comment: the modifier "maximum" should be close to the noun it modifies. Here it refers to the amount, $6,000.

Answer (score 2):

The word "income" is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) and thus cannot be used with an indefinite article. Additionally, the usage and placement of the word "maximum" (which is acting as an adverb with the meaning "at most") is a little awkward; here are some alternative phrasings:

- If you have earned no more than $6000 of employment income this year, . . .
- If your employment income for this year was $6000 or less, . . .
- $6000 is the maximum employment income for which you do not need to declare income tax next year. (Here "maximum" is being used as an adjective rather than an adverb. However, in formal writing, it is better not to begin a sentence with a number.)